# Best practices for .NET Core's BackgroundServices hosted on AWS

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, background-service

Currently I have web api built on top of ASP.NET Core 5  Web Api and it is hosted on AWS (Fargate). In future it is plan to scale it. Now, need for [BackgroundService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/background-tasks-with-ihostedservice) exists because one API endpoint has to generate some report that needs to be uploaded to multiple interested parties since report generation and sending to 3 different endpoint can take 5-10 seconds or even more and client of API is not interested in results of those actions.

My approach is this: create columns inside Report table (SentTo1Side, SentTo2Side, SentTo3Site) and then use background service that "collects" messages from AWS queue I previously put in queue while client of web api called my endpoint. Once sent, I delete message from queue and update SentToXSide columns

My question is:

Should scaling my web api cause that multiple background services are run at the same time? I suppose yes. How to prevent then that multiple reports are sent to the clients. That is reason I used AWS Sqs - maybe is not even needed in my case since I can just loop through database rows to see which reports were not sent).

Comment: Shouldn't you put a message in SQS from API endpoint, and then have a SQS triggered Lambda to process that message, generate reports, share reports  with clients and do other processing asynchronously. This way, you will save cost as well.

Comment: My idea was also to not use backgroundservice but amazon lambda but since have to experience with it didn't consider it as first options. Regarding putting messages to queue: yes, api endpoint will put message to queue that part is easy and I have no doubts what to do there. I guess that is main benefit of lambda: that it can scale but not messages will be taken by two different lambdas hence no duplicates email, reports, whatever will be sent

Comment: For that, you can use SQS FIFO queues, that guarantees exactly-once-processing. But if you want to avoid complexity, you can just check the status of request in database first, and on the basis of that you can take decision in Lambda, whether to proceed or just leave from if block if record/message is already processed. However, there are very rare chances for that to happen, but AWS is not responsible for that as mentioned here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/51587763/1273882.

Answer (score 0):

In perfect scenario you would scale background service (worker) according to throughput. SQS can ensure you that one job is processed once and that job will be reprocessed when something goes wrong.

**Should scaling my web api cause that multiple background services are run at the same time?**
No, scaling should be caused by amount of work required, because processing request is probably faster than processing job.

**How to prevent then that multiple reports are sent to the clients.**
SQS will take care of that for you if you do it right.

Comment: Ok, so when I instance asks "give me all messages" and when next one asks "give me, Amazon will handle that scenario that second time no messages that are sent to instance 1 of my web api will be sent to instance two (because of visibility timeout thing I suppose). When I think about it now actually it is good that I choosen SQS (only because of this feature). Otherwise, I don't see why I should use SQS instead of lopping through database to see reports which were not sent (no many reports are generated, couple each day).

Comment: Scaling of web api is needed because of other things inside web api, not because of background services itself)

Comment: I see your point. Based on your explanation i agree.

Comment: Although you post only job on the queue, not the actual data.
So in situation when you need to proces more things it is background service responsibility to retrieve them from database (as opposed to queue).

Comment: I cannot post data to queue because of size limit of 256 kb (report is HTML that has over 1MB) and also generating it requires getting all data from database that can also take few seconds (at least) which is not of interest to the user sending request to my api endpoint

Comment: I meant that you should not do it. Sorry, my bad